# change site path by RewriteRule3

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path

i need change the site url path

```
from

site.net/open.php?cat=22&book=2285

to

site.net/book/2285
```

i think this code need edit and complite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]*)$ /books/open.php?cat=22&book=$1 [L]
```

how to do it by .htaccess and RewriteRule?

i need code work in all categorys also  not 22 only

Comment: No, you have to pass the cat to url somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work for you -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cat\=22($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)book\=2285($|&)
RewriteRule ^open\.php$ /book/2285? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: this code will work with all categories ? or only categorie number 22 ?? i need the code work with any categorie number and with any book numbers